# tkinter image from url without importing ImageTK, base 64 etc

Tags: python, tkinter, base64

Is there anyway to import a picture into the window, using only methods imported from tkinter, and nothing else? Couldnt find anything specifically about this.

Cheers.

EDIT: From url

Comment: Have a look at this http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/images.html. Now with more recent version of tk, png files are supported as well.

Comment: looks like that method is only for local files :( trying to find a way for image url

Comment: did in the title of the question......

Comment: I had missed the 'from url' in the title.

Comment: all good :) i probably should have said it in the body of text

Comment: With nothing except tkinter? No.

Comment: Turns out it was possible, just had to be a .gif, as per j_4321's answer below.

Comment: @Mvan: you asked about using _only_ tkinter. It's certainly possible when you allow other modules such as urllib.

Comment: Ahh sorry, in my mind I wasnt thinking of it like that. Was for an assignment that already had some base modules loaded in like urlib. Cheers though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to my knowledge, you cannot directly import an image from an url using only Tkinter, but you can fetch the image data first using `urllib`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from urllib.request import urlopen

root = tk.Tk()

url = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a"
with urlopen(url) as handle:
    data = handle.read()

im = tk.PhotoImage(master=root, data=data)

tk.Label(root, image=im).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: think im getting close by using this, might have to use .gif over .jpeg though. cheers